# wp_usermeta - Read from database, but save function broken

Tags: functions, database, mysql, user-meta

I added a custom field to the profile-page of WordPress users called "uidnumber"
and it reads values from the database just fine, however it just doesn't save anything.

[image: wp_usermeta table]

I'd rather save it in wp_users instead if I could because the whole table is just that much more clear, however from what I've read, WordPress updates could delete custom columns.

Here's what I got in my `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id )
{
    update_user_meta( $user_id,'uidnumber', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['uidnumber'] ) );
}
```

and here's the field itself :

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="uidnumber"><?php _e( 'UID-Nummer', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="uidnumber" id="uidnumber" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->uidnumber); ?>" />
            </p>
```

I have no idea why it won't save this field, while another one I coded into the "`contact_methods`", works like a charm.

**edit01:**

I tried what you told me, still doesn't save unless I put it in the wrong place.

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="uidnumber"><?php _e( 'UID-Nummer', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="uidnumber" id="uidnumber" value="<?php echo get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'uidnumber', true ); ?>" />
            </p>
```

Or did you mean to put it in my save function? (As you mentioned value I assumed otherwise)

**edit02:** I think my main problem is that what you specified in your "show"-function
is actually inside another file in my case: `form-edit-account.php`
So I can't just use your "show_extra_profile_fields" function.

***Also one thing that seems to be misunderstood:*** I want the user (normal user on WordPress) to be able to add his own text. That's the only reason I'm doing this. Personally I can add a UID-Number in the backend just fine. However that means I have to find out the UID for each and every user myself.

**edit03:**

[functions.php](http://pastebin.com/srv4XFs2) - Here only the last couple lines are actually relevant.

[form-edit-account.php](http://pastebin.com/2iFjri1q)

Comment: Well it's saving something, just it's blank! Is `$user->uidnumber` set (in the `<input>`'s value attribute)? Try `get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'uidnumber', true )` instead...

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided the whole code so don't understand where you are wrong, this script is working fine for me.

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id )
{
    if ( current_user_can('edit_user',$user_id) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'uidnumber', sanitize_text_field($_POST['uidnumber']));
}

add_action('show_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields');

function show_extra_profile_fields( $user )
{
    ?>
        <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="uidnumber"><?php _e( 'UID-Nummer', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="input-text" name="uidnumber" id="uidnumber" value="<?php echo get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'uidnumber', true ); ?>" />
        </p>
    <?php
}
```

**EDIT : For frontend code**

You have to save uidnumber through `update_user_meta` here is the code

```
global $user;

$user = wp_get_current_user();

if ( $_POST )   {

    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'uidnumber', sanitize_text_field($_POST['uidnumber']) );
}
```

EDIT 2 : `personal_options_update` action only works in admin section, you have to put that code into front end check [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/hkKBbVND)

[image]

1. [sanitize_text_field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_text_field)
2. [show_user_profile](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/show_user_profile)
3. [edit_user_profile](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile)
4. [personal_options_update](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/personal_options_update)
5. [edit_user_profile_update](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile_update)

Comment: Does not work in my case. Like I said in my edit, it's the frontend, not the backend. Backend edits work just fine.
If you need more information/more code, I'd be happy to provide you with such.

Comment: @theHubi updated code hope this what you are looking for, otherwise need more info. Happy Coding!

Comment: Maybe there are two lines of code conflicting each other or something..

Comment: check edit 2 @theHubi

Comment: I see. I added the code to my php edit-account file, still isn't working. But I'm pretty sure that this is a step in the right direction. Thanks a lot so far!
I'll go check my functions.php again to see if I can figure something out.